# Nightwatch demo test

Tags: nightwatch.js

on the website, the nightwatch.js **demo script** is not valid anymore, Google changed the search engine result page html/css, so the earlier element access does not work. Tried some new ways using elements and xpath but I did not find a solution yet.

```
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.title('Google')
      .assert.visible('input[type=text]')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'rembrandt van rijn')
      .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
      .click('button[name=btnG]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('ol#rso li:first-child',
        'Rembrandt - Wikipedia')
      .end();
  }
};
```

Any idea what to change that runs the test fully and returns correct results?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
      client
        .url('http://www.google.com')
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
        .assert.title(`Google`)
        .setValue('input[type=text]', ['rembrandt van rijn', client.keys.ENTER])
        .waitForElementVisible('input[name=btnK]', 1000)
        .click('input[name=btnK]')
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.containsText('div.srg > div:first-child',
          'Rembrandt - Wikipedia')
        .end();
    }
  };
```